# Using LibCurl in C++ and self signed certificate

Tags: c++, libcurl

I've got a problem using libcurl and ssl.

If I try to connect to my site using the following curl command :

curl -q  --cert client-2048.crt --key client-2048.key https://****** -d "username=***&password=***" -H "X-Application: curlCommandLineTest"

everything works well(the certificate is self signed by the way)

How can I do the same usign libcurl?

I tried to follow the libcurl ssl sample but the certificates and private key
have different extensions so I don't know where to start.

So far I tried the following(and many other combinations) :

```
static const char *pCertFile = "client-2048.crt";
static const char *pCACertFile = "client-2048.pem";
static const char *pKeyName = "client-2048.key";

curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT);

curl = curl_easy_init();
if (curl) {
    /* what call to write: */
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://*****");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADERDATA, headerfile);

        /* cert is stored PEM coded in file... */
        /* since PEM is default, we needn't set it for PEM */
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSLCERTTYPE, "PEM");

        /* set the cert for client authentication */
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, pCertFile);

        /* set the private key (file or ID in engine) */
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, pKeyName);

        /* disconnect if we can't validate server's cert */
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1L);

        /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        /* Check for errors */
        if (res != CURLE_OK)
            fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
                curl_easy_strerror(res));

        /* we are done... */
    } while (0);
    /* always cleanup */
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    return 0;
```

But I get the message :

```
curl_easy_perform() failed: Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with 
given CA certificates
```

So what would it be the Libcurl code to mirror the call that succeed?

Thanks

Comment: Ok here it's probably the fact that curl does much more than that, but first of all the the peer verification needs to be disabled becasue it's a self signed certificate.

Comment: convert any curl command line into libcurl source code with `--libcurl source.c` - as a first step

Answer (score 5):

Self Signed Certificate :

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);

Comment: Warning, this solution turns off validation of certificates.  To do validation yourself, you need to install a context function:
  curl_easy_setopt ( curl, CURLOPT_SSL_CTX_FUNCTION, setupPeerVerifyCallback );

And within that function, install a verify callback.
SSL_CTX_set_verify ( psslctx, SSL_VERIFY_PEER, verifyPeerCallback );